# Rails has_many_through and multiple items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have many models using a `has_many_through` relationship: `users`, `roles`, and `security_items`.

A user can be in multiple roles, a role can have many security items. So if a user is in multiple roles, how can I find out if a particular item is any of the roles? Like if its true in one but false in the other, the true should take precedence.

If a user is only in one role then the following works, but if a user is multiple roles then the following fails in `rails console`

```
role = RoleMembership.where("user_id = ?", user.id)
role.security_items.exists?(1)
```

Error if the user is in multiple roles:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `security_items' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_RoleMembership:0x00000102da5e28>`
```

How can I check each and every role to see if the item exists in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Try `role.map(&:security_items).flatten.uniq` to get all the security items.

Answer (score 0):

```
RoleMembership.where("user_id = ?", user.id).select { |role| role.security_items.present? }
```

Working upon the code that you put up, thats how I would do it.

EDIT:

If you get the NOMETHOD error, it means there isn't a method called security_items for the role. Is your relationship set up right in the models? You can try in the console

```
RoleMembership.find(1).security_items
```

If that errors out then you have identified your problem.